# How to convert RTF to PDF with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having a bit of a problem converting .RTF File format to .PDF using PDFSharp Version 1.50 my output result is a blank page, I would really appreciate your help and sample code.

Here is my Class code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.Adapters;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;
    using PdfSharp;
    using PdfSharp.Drawing;
    using PdfSharp.Pdf;
    using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
    using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;
    using MigraDoc.Rendering;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    protected void ConvertRtf2Pdf()
    {
        //- Source RTF Filename and path
        var MySourceRTFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/templates/sample.rtf");
        //- Target PDF Filename and path
        var _sFileName = "SAMPLE_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + 
             DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss").Trim().Replace(":", "") + ".pdf";
        var MyTragetPDFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/export/" + FileName);
        //- Read the Source RTF file
        string docfi = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(MySourceRTFile);
        //- Start creating the PDF document
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.AddPage();
        XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);
        XFont font = new XFont("Time New Roman", 0, XFontStyle.Regular);
        graph.DrawString(docfi, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                        XStringFormats.Default);
        //- Final result 
        pdfDoc.Save(MyTragetPDFile);
        pdfDoc.Dispose();
    }
```

What am I missing that the PDF output is completely blank

Thanks
Al

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I don't think it would be a solution for what I am trying to accomplish, I really need a good input on this or at least someone to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the text is there, but white or transparent or whatever. or sizes of the two documents is different, indicating that the text really is not there.

You can find more information and download links for PDFSharp version 1.50.4845-beta4 on the official GitHub repository: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp